# Flex 3: Can anybody see why this dictionary isn't working?

Tags: apache-flex, dictionary

So, in my main mxml, i have a variable defined as such:

```
[Bindable] public var studentsListDict:Dictionary = new Dictionary;
```

I also have the following imported:

```
import flash.utils.Dictionary;
```

I then have an HTTPService that imports an XML file:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="studentsHttp" url="students.xml" resultFormat="e4x" makeObjectsBindable="true" result="createStudentsCollection(event)" />
```

The createStudentsCollection function is as follows:

```
private function createStudentsCollection(e:ResultEvent):void
{
    var xmlList:XMLList = XML(e.result).student;
    var dupString:String = "|";
    var tempArray:Array = new Array;
    studentsListDict = new Dictionary;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < xmlList.length(); i++)
    {
        if (dupString.indexOf(String("|" + xmlList[i].name) + "|") == -1)
        {
            tempArray = new Array;
            tempArray[0] = xmlList[i].name.@id;
            tempArray[1] = xmlList[i].name;
            tempArray[2] = xmlList[i].year;
            tempArray[3] = xmlList[i].track;

            studentsListAC.addItem(tempArray);
            studentsListDict[tempArray[0]] = tempArray;
            dupString += "|" + xmlList[i].name + "|";

            getLen(studentsListDict);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to ensure the items were correctly put into the dictionary, i have the following function:

```
public static function getLen(d:Dictionary):int 
{ 
    var i:int = 0; 
    for (var key:Object in d)
    {
        Alert.show(String(key + "\n" + d[key]));
        i++;
    }
    return i; 
}
```

This creates pop up alerts that show that everything was loaded correctly into the dictionary.

Later on, in a child, I call a function that tries to use the dictionary, and i get a return of "undefined".

Here's the function that searches based on key, and returns a value from the array within:

```
public function getStudentName(sID:Number):String
{
    return studentsListDict[sID][1];
}
```

Unfortunately, the getStudentName function simply returns undefined every time.

If anybody can see something I'm missing, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Brds

**EDIT**

It wasn't working b/c you can't have numbers as keys in a dictionary.  Simply casting them to a string during the declaration and look up seems to work just fine.

Comment: Since everyone here seems to try to teach you, I'll put in my 2 cents ;) You'd better replace that 'tempArray' with a proper model class 'Student' with properties 'id', 'name', 'year' and 'track'. Your code will be much easier to read and debug. Otherwise you could just as well put the XML node itself in that Dictionary and save yourself the copying of those values in that Array. Furthermore, if you're going to keep both an IList and a Dictionary with the same elements, it's going to be harder to keep them in sync when adding/removing elements. Any particular reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

[Here is some documentation on dictionary keys.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=10_Lists_of_data_4.html).

It looks like you're code is setting it as a string and then accessing it as a number.  I suspect that is the root of your problem  You can try something like this:

```
public function getStudentName(sID:Number):String
{
    return studentsListDict[sID.toString()][1];
}
```

---

It is actually perfectly acceptable to use numbers as Keys to a Dictionary.  The Dictionary apparently turns the number and a string value of that number to the same key.  Here is a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            public var dict : Dictionary;

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {

                dict = new Dictionary();
                dict["0"] = "hi";
                dict["4"] = "hola";
                dict["17"] = "bye";
                dict["32"] = "adios";
                dict[32] = "adios 2";
                dict[3.2] = "adios 3";
                dict[50] = "Audio ";
                dict["50"] = "Audio 2";

                trace(dict["0"]);
                trace(dict["4"]);
                trace(dict["17"]);
                trace(dict["32"]);
                trace(dict[32]);
                trace(dict[3.2]);
                trace(dict[50]);
                trace(dict["50"]);


            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: The “… key is either a string or an Object” is a bit misleading…

Comment: You're right; Numbers do in fact work as keys to a Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because `getStudentName` is using a Number as a key, while `createStudentCollection` is using a string. In this case, because the keys are numbers/strings, you can simply use an `Object`: `var studentsListDict:Object = {};` — it will automatically coerce all the keys to strings.

Also, as an asside: `new Dictionary();` more standard, and it's better form in ActionScript to use `[]` (eg, `var foo:Array = []`) than `new Array()`. That way you can put stuff in the array at the same time:

```
var tempArray:Array = [
    xmlList[i].name.@id,
    xmlList[i].name,
    …
];
```

Comment: I figured it out... it's because apparently you can't assign numbers as dictionary keys... so i simply put a String() in the declaration and lookup... works like a champ now.  

Thanks for the array info... duly noted

Comment: -1 because both syntaxes work.  My preference is to always specify the parenthesis '()' when creating a new object, but it is not required.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I think he makes a fair point on the syntax - just because it works in AS3 you shouldn't omit () as it may build bad habits that cause problems in other languages. Personally I'd always go with [] for a new array, but I wouldn't downvote you for it :)

Comment: @tomfumb At your discretion of course, but this answer is an incorrect guess.  It points to an issue that is not actually an issue and has no relation on the actual problem the original poster was facing.  I stand by my -1.

Comment: @Brds: Numbers work fine as Dictionary keys… It's only a problem if you use a Number in one place and a String in another.

Comment: @Flextras: sure, both syntaxes work. It also works if you leave out semicolons xor whitespace. But, in general, ActionScript coders don't do that, because we've got conventions for semicolons and whitespace… And, since it looks like @Brds is fairly new to ActionScript, I thought I'd pass along a couple tips.

Comment: @David Wolever I have no issue trying to educate other users; I just don't see how you actually addressed the problem the user was having.

Comment: @Flextras: ah, yes, my initial answer didn't directly answer it. My current answer does, though.

Comment: @David Wolever I do not see any edits to your answer, but if you have elaboration to the current question, I strongly suggest you edit it.  The latest claim that Numbers as keys are only a problem if you try to access it as a String later is incorrect; and code disproving that has been added to my answer.  IT appears you can use numbers (1) and Strings ("1") interchangeably as keys and they'll return the same value.